# Why does the order of didSet at IBInspectables does not respect the hierarchy?

Tags: swift

Given this two classes:

```
class A: UIView{
    var setMe: Int!
    @IBInspectable var setMePlease: Int = 0{
        didSet{
            setMe = setMePlease
        }
    }
}

class B: A{
    @IBInspectable var control: Bool = false{
        didSet{
            let a = setMe + 1
        }
    }
}
```

It will crash if you first set the value of `control` and than `setMePlease` in the interface builder. Why does the didSet listen rather to the time the value is inserted than the class hierarchy? Is there a way to let the values listen to the hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `setMe` is defined as an implicitly unwrapped optional and if you set `control` before a value is assigned to `setMe` in the property observer of `setMePlease`, the value of `setMe` will be `nil`, causing a crash due to the force unwrapping.

You should either declare `setMe` as a simple optional if a `nil` value actually makes sense or rather provide it a default value.

```
class A: UIView{
    var setMe: Int?
    @IBInspectable var setMePlease: Int = 0{
        didSet{
            setMe = setMePlease
        }
    }
}

class B: A{
    @IBInspectable var control: Bool = false{
        didSet{
            if let setValue = setMe {
                let a = setMe + 1
            } else {
                let a = 1
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Property observers are not called when assigning a default value during initialization, this is why `setMe` is `nil` when accessing it from the property observer of `control`.

This phenomenon can be easily seen using the following code, namely the property observer is only called after programatically changing the value of the variable, it is not called when assigning the default value to it:

```
class Parent{
    var aCopy:Int?
    var a = 1 {
        didSet{
            aCopy = a
        }
    }
}

class Child: Parent {
    var b = 0{
        didSet{
            a = 2
            let c = (aCopy ?? 0) + b
        }
    }
}

let child = Child()
child.aCopy //nil
child.a //1
child.b = 1 //b is assigned a new value, so its property observer is called
child.a //2
child.aCopy //2
```

Comment: I was wondering why the didSet is executing in a different order than the class hierarchy. While the classes are loaded in the order of the class hierarchy, the didSet methods don't. I know why it crashes, the classes A and B are just simple examples.

Comment: @J.Doe check my updated answer. Property observers are not called when assigning a default value to the variable during initialization, hence your issue.